# How to store 32 input parameters in a single solidity function with data types being string and bytes32?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

When I try to exceute a solidity smart conract function to store 32 input parameters, I am getting a stack too deep error.

To resolve that, at the middleware we have consolidated and created an array of bytes32 for 24 input parameters and the rest of the 8 parameters are of string datatype. But again we get the same stack too deep error.

How can I possibly exceute a function to store the 32 input parameters?

We are making use of solidity compiler version 0.4.25.

This is the basic skeletal of code

```
struct Sample {
    bytes32 key;
    string str1;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    string str8;
    byts32[] someArray; //23 elements
}

mapping(bytes32 => Sample) sampleMap;

function set(bytes32 key,string str1,string str2,......,string str8,bytes32[] array) public returns(bool) {
    //set the values using sampleMap mapping;
    return true;
}

function get(bytes32 key) returns(bytes32 key,string str1,string str2,......,string str8,bytes32[] array) {
    //retrieve values from struct using sampleMap mapping
}
```

Comment: Link to your code?

Comment: Have edited the question to include basic skeletal of code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of having a stack push so heavy in EVM/solidity.

Pass the address of a storage array to be filled just before the call or, better, write your input parameters in a suitable public struct or data repository and call the function without any parameter, accessing the data directly in storage area.

The concept is:

```
p1 = argument n.1
p2 = argument n.2
.
.
.
pn= argument n. N

foo();
```

Where in foo() some elaboration using p1...pN is realized

instead of

```
foo(p1, p2, ..., pN)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the ABIV2Encoder, then you can do this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Example {
    struct Sample {
        bytes32 key;
        string str1;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        string str8;
        byts32[] someArray; //23 elements
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Sample) sampleMap;

    function set(Sample data) public returns(bool) {
        sampleMap[data.key] = data;
        return true;
    }

    function get(bytes32 key) returns(Sample) {
        return sampleMap[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a `Stack too deep exception` I would break it down in small transactions doing one transaction to store one string.

```
struct StringStorage {
    bytes32 key; // Key
    mapping(uint => string) strings; // Each strings is associated to an index
}

mapping(bytes32 => StringStorage) db; // Global storage

/*
 * Create a StringStorage
 */
function createStringStorage(bytes32 _key) public returns(bool) {
    require(db[_key].key[0] == 0, "StringStorage already exists");

    db[key].key = _key;

    return true;
}

/*
 * Add a string to a StringStorage for a given index
 */
function set(bytes32 _key, uint _index, string _str) public returns(bool) {
    require(db[_key].key[0] != 0, "StringStorage doesn't exist");

    db[key].strings[_index] = _str;

    return true;
}

/*
 * Returns a given string in a StringStorage
 */
function get(bytes32 _key, uint _index) returns(string) {
    return db[_key].strings[_index];
}
```